# Does Databricks offer something like Oracle's dblink?

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I am aware, I can load anything into a DataFrame using JDBC, that works well from Oracle sources. Is there an equivalent in Spark SQL, so I can combine datasets as well?

Basically something like so - you get the idea...

```
select
    lt.field1,
    rt.field2
from localTable lt
join remoteTable@serverLink rt
    on rt.id = lt.id
Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an upcoming [Query Federation](https://docs.databricks.com/query-federation/index.html) functionality that allows to access tables in other databases by registering them in Databricks SQL.

Answer (score 0):

dblink does not exist. You can create two table statements with JDBC sources and then join the two tables. It will be a little more to write, but you'll get the correct table.

In python, you can maybe do it easier with something like:

<!— begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```html
spark.read.jdbc(config1).join(spark.read.jdbc(config2), "key", "type")
```